# tags$pre adds spaces for each div

Tags: shiny

Anybody knows why `tags$pre` adds spaces for each nested div?

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    tags$pre("Line 1","Line 2"),
    div(tags$pre("Line 1","Line 2")),
    div(div(tags$pre("Line 1","Line 2")))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
))
```

[image]

After inspecting the elements in the browser, it seems tha `tags$pre` adds spaces at the beginning of each line based on how deep the `tags$pre` function is. Please note that in this simplified code I can just remove the `div's` but I need the `div's`.

How can I have the same margin of each `pre`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `pre` tag preserves all whitespace (pre = preformatted), and Shiny automatically formats HTML code to be human readable by indenting it.

If interested, you can find out the culprit by digging into shiny/htmltools a bit. I wanted to verify this so I found where this happens.

```
> mytag <- div(div())

> mytag
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

yup, looks like it prints with indentation. So let's see what print method is called

```
> class(mytag)
[1] "shiny.tag"

> getS3method("print", "shiny.tag")
function (x, browse = is.browsable(x), ...) 
{
    if (browse) 
        html_print(x)
    else print(as.character(x), ...)
    invisible(x)
}
<environment: namespace:htmltools>
```

redirected to as.character, so let's see what that does

```
> getS3method("as.character", "shiny.tag")
function (x, ...) 
{
    renderTags(x)$html
}
<environment: namespace:htmltools>
```

redirected to renderTags, let's look there

```
> htmltools:::renderTags
function (x, singletons = character(0), indent = 0) 
{
    x <- tagify(x)
    singletonInfo <- takeSingletons(x, singletons)
    headInfo <- takeHeads(singletonInfo$ui)
    deps <- resolveDependencies(findDependencies(singletonInfo$ui))
    headIndent <- if (is.numeric(indent)) 
        indent + 1
    else indent
    headHtml <- doRenderTags(headInfo$head, indent = headIndent)
    bodyHtml <- doRenderTags(headInfo$ui, indent = indent)
    return(list(head = headHtml, singletons = singletonInfo$singletons, 
        dependencies = deps, html = bodyHtml))
}
<environment: namespace:htmltools>
```

there it is. The indentation happens right here

just to be sure, let's test that

```
> htmltools:::renderTags(mytag, indent = 5)
$head


$singletons
character(0)

$dependencies
list()

$html
          <div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
```

mystery solved

Comment: Great explanation @daattali it make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be working:

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    tags$pre("Line 1\nLine 2"),
    div(tags$pre("Line 1\nLine 2")),
    div(div(tags$pre("Line 1\nLine 2")))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
))
```

As it says [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp), a `pre` tag respects formatting, so avoid shinys html-formatting rules by directly inserting the desired character string.

Comment: It works!, For an vector of character I can use `paste0(lines, collapse ="\n")` Thank you.